# JQuery - Image not shifting left or right on button click

Tags: jquery

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery Test</title>
  <style>
    /* basic setup */
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    /* properties for html page */
    html {
      background-color: #008B8B;
    }
    /* Image properties */
    img {
      float: left;
      height: 120px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $("img").addClass("wrappedElement");

      $("#Right-Shift").click(function() {
        $("img").slideRight();
      });

      $("#Left-Shift").click(function() {
        $("img").slideLeft();
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="header">
    <button id="Right-Shift">Right Shift</button>
    <button id="Left-Shift">Left Shift</button>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo1.jpg" alt="one">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo2.jpg" alt="two">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo3.jpg" alt="three">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo4.jpg" alt="four">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo5.jpg" alt="five">
    <img class="photo" src="images/photo6.jpg" alt="six">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
The JQuery in this html is Not working for left or right shift of images as given. Not sure this is correct, any pointer would be helpful
The JQuery in this html is Not working for left or right shift of images as given. Not sure this is correct, any pointer would be helpful
The JQuery in this html is Not working for left or right shift of images as given. Not sure this is correct, any pointer would be helpful
The JQuery in this html is Not working for left or right shift of images as given. Not sure this is correct, any pointer would be helpful
```

Comment: I have 6 images to shift right or left based on a button click, the above JQuery code is not working.

Comment: Please provide the html code in the question.

Comment: I edited and copied the entire html. Can you pls. check what is missing in this to shift the images either left or right based on click of the respective buttons.

Comment: where is the implemenation of `slideRight` ?

Comment: I edited and added the complete html code in to the post. Can you pls. check what is wrong in this code for shifting the images either left or right based on the click event of the button.

Comment: I politely repeat, Where is the code for `slideLeft` ?

Comment: is there a sample format someone could provide using JQuery function to shift images left or right based on a button click as given

Answer (score 0):

.slideRight is not a native Jquery function.

http://api.jquery.com/?s=slide

This is why it isn't working.

I would suggest to write the function yourself or use an opensource JQuery carousel.
There are plenty of opensource carousels and sliders out there so no need to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: You could use something like this: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

Pretty easy to implement

Comment: This is an example that looks more like what you need: http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html

Comment: I am including JQuery library as below, I tried the second sample ( owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/custom.html) given, but not sure the JQuery library has this owl. The code doesn't work as given. Any other simple sample format you could share for this code requirements                                                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Hey @ManiGounder ,

Sorry for the late response, check out the how to. You need to download the owl .js files and include it AFTER the JQuery script.

Check out the How To:
http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html#how-to